# Raspbian crashing after servo.stop_servo()

Tags: raspbian, gpio, python, pwm, servo

I have a servo connected to my RPi and I try PWM.Servo's capabilities. The program below does what it should - but after execution it crashes system (it doesn't respond to any input, no animations, nothing). I sincerely have no idea how to solve this.

```
from RPIO import PWM
import time

servo = PWM.Servo()

servo.set_servo(15, 1200)
time.sleep(5)
servo.set_servo(15, 2000)
time.sleep(5)

servo.stop_servo(15)
```

Unfortunately, I haven't found anything on the internet to help me. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Today I have found that the problem occurs even without `servo.stop_servo()`. Programs that do not use PWM.Servo are working OK though. But **when I run the program from terminal (`sudo python /home/pi/Desktop/servo.py`) it works like a charm**. Why does it crush system when run on IDLE?

Comment: Does this happen when the servo is disconnected from the RPi or only when it is connected?

Comment: @Craig it doesn't matter if it is connected

Comment: Does the version of IDLE you have installed match the version number from typing "python -V" at the terminal? It's possible there is a version mismatch between the two and this sounds similar to a problem I had because of it.